# How to Delete data in NSManagedObject Context in CoreData

Tags: iphone

I have make simple coredata Example with Field Entry :

Name :***_*___**  &
Phone Number :**__*_*__** .

I save that Value entry in CoreDat database..

i want to delete the entry for perticular name..

So How can i make to be perform.

Thanks,

Keyur Prajapati

Answer (score 3):

You need to iterate the core data values and get the object you wish to delete (You may also use predicates to get object)

```
[context deleteObject:yourObject];
```

Comment: Thanks. Friend. I have try and by set objects of NSManagedObjectContext and NSpredicate in NSFetchRequest, and from that returned array we can delete NSManagedObject from particu;ar Index.